# Adding class when .next() reaches end of .length()?

Tags: jquery

Im almost there but my jQuery is not adding the class at the right time, there is an extra two clicks.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X7L8q/4/

**jQuery:**

```
  var currentItem = $('.item').filter('.active');

  $('#next-button').on('click', function () {
      var nextItem = currentItem.next();
      currentItem.removeClass('active');

      //Here is the meat of the code, its adding the class a few clicks later than I want.
      if (nextItem.length) {
          currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
      } else if (nextItem.length == 0) {
          $('.item:last').addClass('red');
          alert('class red added');
      }

  });
```

**HTML:**

The jQuery should add the class to the last item when `#next-button` is clicked we add `.active` to the `.next()` item, but then if `nextItem` == 0 we add class red the problem is it happens two clicks late.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7L8q/4/) to see what I mean.

```
  <div class="item active" data-category="sharks">content1</div>
  <div class="item" data-category="tigers">content2</div>
  <div class="item" data-category="lions">content3</div> 
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="next-button" rel="nofollow">Next</a>
```

*WOW all these answers are good! Thanks guys!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var items = $('.item'), currentItem = items.filter('.active'), last = items.last();

$('#next-button').on('click', function () {
    currentItem.removeClass('active');
    var nextItem = currentItem.next();

    if (nextItem.length) {
        currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
        if (currentItem.is(last)) {
            $('.item:last').addClass('red');
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wRt4B/)

Comment: I take it back this is much more sound, I like this.. I wish I could award two answers, they are both great. When fiddling with it earlier before I posted I had something close to this, im going to try and find where I was off. Thanks Arun

Answer (score 1):

Hope i understood your problem, what you want is then when it is the last item in the list just make the color red. If this is your problem then this code will definately help you

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="item active" data-category="sharks">content1</div>
<div class="item" data-category="tigers">content2</div>
<div class="item" data-category="lions">content3</div> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="next-button" rel="nofollow">Next</a>
```

Script:

```
    var currentItem = $('.item').filter('.active');

    $('#next-button').on('click', function () {
        var nextItem = currentItem.next();
        currentItem.removeClass('active');

        if (nextItem.length) {
            currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
            if (nextItem.length <= 1) {
                $('.item:last').addClass('red');
            }
        } else if (nextItem.length == 0) {
            alert('class red added');
        }

    });
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    display: none;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/X7L8q/8/)

Comment: Yes, this is it.. Im no good with those operators <= I need to wrap my head around them... :) thanks

Comment: Yeah you nailed it.. im not actually adding color red to my real code, this was for demo purposes just adding a class to the last item. Now that you helped me I can have some fun with it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by usage of `.next` method without specifying additional selector. In your case the hyperlink `next-button` is selected after the last item.

You may use `.next` method this way:

```
var nextItem = currentItem.next('.item');
```

so after the last element link will not be selected.

Also I would recommend to move this line of code:

```
currentItem.removeClass('active');
```

inside the `if` block to avoid removing `active` class for the last item.

Try it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7L8q/10/)

Comment: This was close, except the class needs to be added before "content 3" appears, well as it appears, Abhishek Jain got it by using <= I really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7L8q/6/)

`.next()` will by give you the next sibling.  `.next('.item')` will give you the next sibling with the class item.

Also, the filter isn't necessary.  You can just do this.

var currentItem = $('.item.active');

```
$('#next-button').on('click', function () {
    var nextItem = currentItem.next('.item');

    if (nextItem.length) {
        currentItem.removeClass('active');
        currentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
    } else if (nextItem.length == 0) {
        $('.item:last').addClass('red');
        alert('class red added');
    }

});
```